# google charts timelines element border-radius

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem figuring out how to set the border-radius on elements in a google charts Timeline. I have looked through all the options but there doesn't seem to be one for that.
I have tried manually setting it but without any luck.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

thx in advance

Comment: Add the code you tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the chart elements can be modified when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

however, the chart will revert back to the original style on any interactivity

a `MutationObserver` can be used to know when the chart has been modified
in order to re-apply the custom style / border radius

the chart is drawn using svg, to change the border radius on a `rect` element,
set attributes `'rx'` and `'ry'`

see the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
  ]);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(setBorderRadius);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setBorderRadius();
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function setBorderRadius() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
      if (parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) > 0) {
        rect.setAttribute('rx', 20);
        rect.setAttribute('ry', 20);
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank you a million times :))))))))))))

Comment: just one more question: does the graph itself need to have the border radius or can it be removed? i just need it for the bars

Comment: sure, that was my original answer, i've rolled it back, see above answer again. just need a way to find the elements you want to change -- here, the `'x'` attribute is used...